# Path Homotopy of Concatenated Paths

Tags: algebraic-topology

If I have two concatenated paths $f_{1} \cdot g_{1}$ and $f_{2} \cdot g_{2}$ where $f_{1} \cong f_{2}$ and $g_{1} \cong g_{2}$, is it fair to say

$$f_{1} \cdot g_{1} \cong f_{2} \cdot g_{2}$$

by the homotopy $(f \cdot g)_{t} = (1-t)(f_{1} \cdot g_{1})+t(f_{2} \cdot g_{2})$?

Comment: What does + mean?

Comment: @Randall its addition? I'm wanting to do a line segment homotopy from $f_{1} \cdot g_{1}$ to $f_{2} \cdot g_{2}$. Sorry I'm a bit confused by your question.

Comment: General topological spaces don’t have an addition.

Comment: @Randall Ah, I understand your question now. So all we can say about a homotopy $h$ is $h(x,0) = f_{1} \cdot g_{1}$ and  $h(x,1) = f_{2} \cdot g_{2}$ if we are dealing in some general topological space $X$.

Comment: What is $\cdot$ here? Composition?

Comment: @GuidoA Yes its the product path. First $f$ then $g$.

Comment: I am then confused: if you can compose the paths, they should all have a (co) domain contained in $[0,1]$. The latter is contractible, so any path $[0,1] \to [0,1]$ is homotopic to the constant path $c_0$. In particular we get $f_1g_1 \simeq f_2g_2$. Or do you mean that only the $g_i$ are paths? In any case, the codomain of the $f_i$ should have a vector space structure or something similar to make sense of the homotopy that you propose. Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: @GuidoA. I am supposed to find a formula for a path homotopy between the paths $f_{1}g_{1}$ and $f_{2}g_{2}$ on a topological space $X$ where each $f_{i},g_{i}$ are themselves paths and $f_{1} \cong f_{2}$ and $g_{1} \cong g_{2}$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: consider for each $t \in I$ the (path) composition $H_t := F_t*G_t$ where $F: f_1 \simeq f_2$ and $G: g_1 \simeq g_2$. Prove that this defines a homotopy of paths: to justify the 'gluing' of the functions, use that both $F$ and $G$ fix the extrema of their corresponding paths.